# stack overflow error in quick sort

Tags: c, quicksort

when i run the program for quick sort in VS2013 i get the following error:"First-chance exception at 0x008B18D9 in quicksort.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00232F68).

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

```
void part(int arr[], int min, int max)
{

srand(time(NULL));

*emphasized text*int pivot, l, i;

if ((max - min) > 0)

    {
        pivot = rand() % max;
        swap(arr, pivot, max);
        l = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[max])
            {
                swap(arr, i, l);
                l++;
            }
        }
        swap(arr, l, max);
        part(arr, min, (l - 1));
        part(arr, (l + 1), max);
    }
}
```

thak you.

Comment: Wild guess: your pivot choice is bad and you have too many levels of recursion. Look up the implementation of `qsort` in glibc to see a good one.

Comment: How does `swap`exactly works? If you set `l` initially to `0`, aren't you going off the limits of the current slice? Also, what @R-Sahu told you.

Comment: Did you have a question you wanted to ask? You told a story and dumped some code; now ask a *specific* question about the code. I note that "I can't find my bugs" is not a question and is not specific.

Comment: thank you sergey L & also  javidcf.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of the pivot should be between `min` and `max-1`. You need something like:

```
    pivot = min + rand() % (max - min);
```

Comment: To expand on R Sahu's point: If your chosen pivot is less than min, you will add a level of recursion without reducing the problem.  Thus, your algorithm will recurse an arbitrary number of times.  The higher min/max becomes, the more often these useless pivots will occur.  It's feasible to reach a recursion depth where min/max > 0.99, so the frequency of useless recursion can quickly become very high.

Comment: thank you R Shau and also Brian. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try recursing into the smaller part of the array first:

```
if (2 * l < max - min) {
    part(arr, min, (l - 1));
    part(arr, (l + 1), max);
} else {
    part(arr, (l + 1), max);
    part(arr, min, (l - 1));
}
```

This will remove the random recursion depth and make it logarithmic.

Comment: I know what tail recursion is, but will this work inside if statement?